# How to confirm if a task is completed before finalizing the thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, splash-screen

I'm getting data from a server for my app. The "getData" functions are included in the app's main Activity, in a splash thread. The problem I'm having is this:

If I quickly enter news or description after loading up the app, I notice that not all info has loaded (last 2 or 3 strings that needed to be saved are null). If, however, I allow the app a few more seconds after displaying the main menu (after completing the splash thread), the problem doesn't occur, all info is stored correctly on the phone. I tried delaying the splash screen by a few seconds but that's not really an elegant solution nor does it always work.

My question is how can I make sure that the functions have been completed before it jumps to "finally"

I'm not storing the data in any database, just in public static string arrays in another class.

You have my code below:

```
if(networkAvailable()){
        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    getData.execute(description_Hyperlinks);
                    getNews.execute(new String[]{newsJSON_Hyperlink});
                    getOffers.execute(new String[]{offersJSON_Hyperlink});

                    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(FlexFormActivity.this, MainMenu.class));
                    stop();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
```

Comment: You should use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that kind of asynchronous working. It gives you the possibility to do certain things as the work on the task progresses.

Comment: getData, getNews and getOffers are instances of AsyncTask classes.

Comment: Then you haven't understand the concept. It would be a better approach to create one single `AsyncTask` (called e.g. "LoadContents") which does _all_ the work. In this task you can then load data, news and offers and display them. When the task has finished, everything is set up and you can show it to the user. You should _never_ need to use a `Thread`, Java's executor-framework and Androids implementations should always wrap this up for you.

Comment: I see...the point of having a thread was to create a splash-screen mostly, that would not appear when pressing the back button. (I preffered a splash screen to overwriting the back button as someone suggested to me...)

Comment: You would show the splash before the task starts and hide it (or start another activity), when it has finished. Although I understand the idea of "disabling" the back button, It isn't a good idea in my eyes. Imagine you accedently opened an app that takes ~10 seconds to load it contents from the internet and you have to wait the whole time only to close it then. For an `AsyncTaks`, there is an easy way of canceling it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You're right, I was trying to cut a few corners I guess, which is always a bad idea. If you'll submit what you told me in the comments as an answer I'll accept it right away :D

Comment: wrapped it up and put it as an answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For the purpose of making the discussion in the comments on the initial question more readable and physically visible*

---

It would be a better idea to use the Android build-in support for asynchronous task-handling in form of the [`AsyncTask`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This allows you to "hook in" the task, giving you the opportunity to react on the different stages of the progress.

The idea would be to not make `getData`, `getNews` and `getOffers` each extend `AsyncTask`, but to rather have a single task (called e.g. "LoadContents"), which loads the data, the news and the offers one after another.

It would then be possible to determine, when the whole initial work has been done, which makes it easy to react on this "completion of task", in whatever form you can imagine.

---

As a little code-review, It should normally never be necessary to use the `Thread`-class itself, as Java and Android provide many wrappers around it (in particular the [Java Executor Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)), which should be favored in order to produce more clean and reliable code.

---

Also, as a general advice on "disabling the back-button" (which is used by @Eugen to ensure that the splash-screen stays present): *Don't* do it. It's not the kind of behavior a user expects when he uses an application.

Imagine someone has accedently opened an app, which takes ~10 seconds for the initial loading of contents, and this process can't be canceled. The user will have to wait the entire time, only to then leave the app without using it.

Therefore, you should not "deactivate" the back-button, but rather make your task (and therefore the initial loading of your application) "cancel-able". When using an `AsyncTask`, this is already implemented for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I didn't use overwritting of the back button though, someone suggested it to me, but also found it a bad idea :D